# How to show side menu by event listener?

Tags: codenameone

There is a side menu called topBar in a Container.
I add an icon in the main toolbar. This should acitvate the side menu.
I deactivated the Hamburger icon in the theme.
Now I cannot reach the side menu. tb is the main toolbar.

Code so far:

```
Container topBar = BorderLayout.north(new Label(icon));
    topBar.add(BorderLayout.WEST, new Label("Cool App Tagline...", "SidemenuTagline")); 
    topBar.setUIID("SideCommand");
    tb.addCommandToLeftBar("", icon, (e) -> XXXXX);
```

I cannot find the start function for the side menu, see xxxxx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `tb.openSideMenu()` see [our javadocs](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/).